# Android - populate a matrix type view (not scrollable) with single 32x32 bitmap image

Tags: android, bitmap, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to develop a pathfinding app that implements A*.

To begin with, I need to display the navigation cells.
I need to use a single 32 pixel square bitmap that represents the navigation cells in columns and rows (before I load the blocker cells, start point, and end point).

They need to fill the screen in a matrix based on the bitmap width and height - it's ok if it goes off the vertical and horizontal edge.

I'm having trouble determining what type of layout and view to use and how to lay it out.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a straightforward case for using `LinearLayout`s.

They:
populate vertically and horizontally
can size according to the content
do not scroll
will bleed off the screen
you can dynamically populate them

It should only be one vertical layout and then a series of horizontal layouts. Or one horizontal and then a series of vertical layouts.

A `TableLayout` might sound appropriate and it could work. But you have to do more work to tell the table how to behave to get results like what you are describing, IMO.